# preg_replace HTML code in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove string like below from a html code
`<span style="font-size: 0.8px; letter-spacing: -0.8px; color: #ecf6f6">3</span>`

so I came up with regex.

`$pattern = "/<span style=\"font-size: \\d(\\.\\d)?px; letter-spacing: -\\d(\\.\\d)?px; color: #\\w{6}\">\\w\\w?</span>/um";`

However, regex doesn’t work. Can someone point me what i did wrong. I'm new to PHP.

when I tested with a simple regex, it works so problem remains with the regex.

```
  $str = $_POST["txtarea"];
  $pattern = $_POST["regex"];
  echo preg_replace($pattern, "", $str);
```

Comment: Why are you using `/um`? Doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: I just wrote a regex and get php regex pattern generated. not sure what's that in PHP as well. Removing it still doesn't fix the problem though.

Comment: Enable `error_reporting`, then google the resulting warning.

Comment: What are the rules for what you want removed?

Comment: @KennethK. basically what inside <span> that has style like `style="font-size: 0.8px; letter-spacing: -0.8px; color: #ecf6f6`

Comment: Also, you forgot to escape the `/` in `</span>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I would advocate [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) to do the job here, you would still need some regular expression down the line, so ...

The expression for the `px` numeric value can be simply `[\d.-]+`, since you're not trying to validate anything.

The contents of the span can be simplified to `[^<]*` (i.e. anything but a opening bracket):

```
$re = '/<span style="font-size: [\d.-]+px; letter-spacing: [\d.-]+px; color: #[0-9a-f]{3,6}">[^<]*<\/span>/';

echo preg_replace($re, '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Do not use regex for this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1253312). Use an html parser. Here is a solution in python with BeautifulSoup, because I like this library for these tasks:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

with open('Path/to/file', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
for div in soup.findAll('span', {'style':re.compile("font-size: \d(\.\d)?px; letter-spacing: -\d(\.\d)?px; color: #\w{6}")}):
    div.extract()

with open('Path/to/file.modified', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write(str(soup))
```

Comment: That doesn't look like PHP to me.

Comment: I don't think OP absolutely needs php, they just picked it.

Comment: Yeah I like php as much as anyone else, but beautifulsoup is a great tool, and you gotta use the right tool for the job. http://www.codinghorror.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b017742d249d5970d-800wi

Comment: PHP has DOMDocument too, so I'm not sure where you were going with that comment :)

Comment: I'm just not familiar with DOMDocument.

Answer (score 0):

you have a slash ( / ) in your ending tag ( closing span )

you need to escape it or to use a different delimiter than slash